# Using stubs also as mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit.net

I've got a class say a `ChatService` and I have a method named `JoinRoom()` that returns void. This method takes a user and their connection details as parameters, and it saves the user to the database together with it's connection details or it adds the connection details for the user in the database if the user already exist in the database, and then raise an event depending irrespective of either condition. I want to test that the method:

1. Saves a new user and their connection details (for new users)
2. Saves the connection details for an existing user.
3. Raise an event when either of the above operation succeeds.

I've got test that checks if the user and their connection is saved correctly and also to check if the event is raised properly. example:

```
    [Fact]
    public void user_should_be_created_and_added_to_the_room_if_user_does_not_exist()
    {
        chatService.JoinRoom(validConnectionId, validRoom, validUsername);

        Assert.False(userExist);
        Assert.True(repository.AddUserCalled);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void then_connection_should_be_added_for_an_existing_user()
    {
        repository.AddUser(new User(validUsername, userpix));
        repository.AddUserCalled = false;

        chatService.JoinRoom(validConnectionId, validRoom, validUsername, userpix);

        Assert.False(repository.AddUserCalled);
        Assert.True(repository.ConnectionAdded);
        Assert.Equal(1, repository.NoOfConnectionAdded);
    }
```

I've got separate test that checks if the event was properly raised, but my worries are that is it right to assert on my fake repository or,  should the repository act as a stub and then I should assert if the event was raised. It seems as though the test is concerned about the internals of the method under test which I don't if it's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question lacks context of how `JoinRoom` will be consumed, but few issues emerge nonetheless:

- why is `JoinRoom` *creating users*? What user creation has to do with joining room? Shouldn't you already be some kind of user before you even can join room (with new users joining *anonymously* perhaps)? I'd revisit this feature.
- connectionId and userName both sound like identification properties of connected user; this could be addressed when *user creation* issue above is solved (you shouldn't need both at same time)
- any reason you're using (what seems as) hand-rolled mocks instead of library generated ([Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4), [FakeItEasy](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy))?

In its current state your tests seem alright (it's not too uncommon to use component as both stub and mock in single test). having points above in mind, I'd change `JoinRoom` to:

```
void JoinRoom(Room room, UserConnectionInfo userConnectionInfo)
```

Or (this would require connection extraction somewhere inside):

```
void JoinRoom(Room room, User user)
```

Comment: thanks @jimmy_keen I'll have to revisit this feature because the method is doing more than what it suggest.